# sort points of interest by distance between each other

Tags: java

I have an array with point-objects as an input. I want to sort these points, that I get an Array with the shortest route covering all the points. this is my code so far, but i havent figuered out, how to delete points, once they have been used.

```
public Point[] poiSort(Point[] poi){
        poi = new Point[lenght+1];
        poi[0] = points[0];
        distances = new Double[lenght];
        double Distance = verybignumber;
        double Distancecompare;
        for (int i = 1; i < leght+1; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j < (lenght); j++){
                Distancecompare = points[i-1].getDistance(points[j]);
                if (Distance > Distancecompare){
                    Distance = Distancecompare;
                    poi[i] = points[j];
                    distances[i-1] = Disstance;
                }
            }
        }
        return poi;
    }
```

Comment: Variable names should begin in lowercase, so they don't get confused with class names, which starts in uppercase.

Comment: The length variable is never initialized and is once written wrongly (leght).

Comment: Why does your method expect an array when you ignore it anyway?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are apparently trying to solve doesn't make sense.

Or at least ... the subproblem doesn't.

If you have `N` points, then the *number* of pair-wise distances between them is `(N-1)^2`.  For each given point P, there are `N - 1` distances to other points.  You can't define a relevant / easily computable ordering for the points based on that.  So sorting doesn't make sense.

What you *could* do is to take one point and order (and sort) the others based on the distance to that point.  But that means for a total of N points you have N separate orderings.

Note that what you are trying to solve here is a form of the ["Traveling Salesman<sup>1</sup> Problem" (TSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).  TSP has been mathematically proven to be an [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) problem.  That should tell you that *attempting* to solve it by sorting (which is `O(NlogN)`) is not to work.

My advice would be:

1. Do some reading on the TSP and why it is hard
2. Try to avoid having to find an exact solution to the problem
3. Look at the techniques / algorithms for finding approximate solutions ... rather than trying to invent your own algorithm.
4. Look for an existing library.

---

<sup>1 - Or the "Traveling Salesperson Problem".  No, I'm not kidding.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can build a new array during sorting and return it as result. This way you do not need to delete elements. Alternatively, you could use an ArrayList or a TreeSet for more flexibility.
Here a maybe not so elegant, but working example with arrays:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Optional;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        
        Point[] points = {new Point(1,1), new Point(3,3), new Point(2,2)};
        Point[] result = sort(points);
        for (Point p : result) {
            System.out.println("point(" + p.x + ", " + p.y + ")");
        }
        
    }
    
    public static Point[] sort(Point[] in) {
        if (in == null || in.length == 0) {
            return in;
        }
        Point[] out = new Point[in.length];
        Point current = in[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
            if (i == in.length -1) {
                out[in.length -1] = Arrays.stream(in).filter(p -> !p.visited).findAny().orElseGet(null);
                break;
            }
            final Point finalCurrent = current;     // variable must be final or effectively final as used in stream
            out[i] = finalCurrent;
            finalCurrent.visit();
            Point next = Arrays.stream(in).filter(p -> !p.visited).min(Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> p.getDistance(finalCurrent))).get();
            current = next;
        }
        return out;
    }
}



class Point {
    final double x;
    final double y;
    boolean visited;
    
    Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public double getDistance(Point point) {
        return Math.abs(this.x-point.x) + Math.abs(this.y - point.y);
    }
    
    public void visit() {
        visited = true;
    }

}
```